# Why do I get an error when I want to rerun one of my functions?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a rock, paper, scissors program on Python but whenever I run my program it gives me an error saying this,

```
File "C:/Users/Home/PycharmProjects/untitled/hi.py", line 59, in <module>
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? y/n")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

I know you might want my code so here it is,

```
from random import *
import os, pygame
moves = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']


def game():

    move=choice(moves)
    player = input("pick a move, 1. Rock, 2. Paper, 3. Scissors")


    if (player == 1 and move == 1):

        print(move, player)
        print("It is a tie!")

    if (player == 1 and move == 2):

        print (move, player)
        print("The computer wins!")

    if (player == 1 and move == 3):

        print (move, player)
        print("You win!")

    if (player == 2 and move == 1):

        print (move, player)
        print("You win!")

    if (player == 2 and move == 2):

        print (move, player)
        print("It's a tie!")

    if (player == 2 and move == 3):

        print (move, player)
        print("The computer wins!")

    if (player == 3 and move == 2):

        print (move, player)
        print("You win!")

    if (player == 3 and move == 3):

        print (move, player)
        print("It's a tie!")

    if (player == 3 and move == 1):

        print (move, player)
        print("The computer wins!")

game()

play_again = input("Do you want to play again? y/n")

if(play_again == "y"):
    game()
```

May you please help me? Thank you

Comment: You're running python 2 and `input` is not doing what you think it is. In python 2 you should be using `raw_input`

Comment: I am positive that this is the code that I am runnin

Comment: oh right thank you I forgot to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running Python2. `input` in Python2 tries to interpret the user's entry as code. `y` doesn't mean anything (it's a `NameError` unless you've declared a variable `y`, but regardless it's not `"y"`). `1`, `2`, and `3` *do* mean something (as used earlier in your code)

You should always use `raw_input` in Py2, which interprets the user's entry as a string. You'll have to adjust your earlier `if` statements to be strings as well (`if player == "1" and moves == 1` and etc)